# Is there any portable or at least vendor-specific way to detect if a Unix socket is orphaned?

Tags: unix, system-calls, unix-socket

When a process creates UDS and exits abnormally, it leaves a socket file behind. On the next run, the program may have troubles seeing the file already exists.

Is there any way to detect if a socket file is orphaned? The best way should be POSIX and available on any UNIX brand, but something Linux/FreeBSD/Solaris/whatever-specific is of use as well.

**I'm not asking on how to**

- make `/tmp` get cleared on reboot. Sometimes app crash without reboot.
- use any GUI or even command-line tool to check it manually.
- remove list of files before running a program or put an `unlink` before `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like I was just one step from the answer.

1. There is nothing like `SO_REUSEADDR` for UDS, and I do believe that's for good reason
2. There is a way to guard socket file with lock file, which is a (relatively) clean and sane way

Using `/tmp/socket.lock` to guard a `/tmp/socket`, we have to

1. open it with `O_RDONLY | O_CREAT`
2. flock it with `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB`

and never do anything with the guard. If flock is successful on next run, than no process hold the lock file, resp., no process use the socket. We are ok to remove it.

Of course, we assume that every program using the socket uses the protocol as well.

Details are at [Victor Gadov's github](https://gavv.github.io/articles/unix-socket-reuse/), copied here due to fragile nature of links in Internet.